# Azure Site-to-Site Networking

Tags: windows, networking, azure, vpn

I'm a little stuck when trying to configure an Azure site-to-site network. I'm using this to connect from Azure into another site for remote management of multiple devices there.

Currently, I believe the majority of the set up to be completed but I now need to secure public IP address for the external site so that they can add these to their firewall rules. Does anyone know how I am meant to acquire the public IP of the VM (which changes each time it is shut down and restarted) or the sites public IP connection to the external site?

Alternatively, what's the best way of doing this? I feel like a site-to-site network doesn't quite fit in with what I'm trying to do but I'm only being offered this solution from the external site (not necessarily just using Azure, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a static IP to your VM:

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/22/static-internal-ip-address-for-virtual-machines/

Comment: That looks to be a private IP address rather than public? Does the Azure VM not need a public IP address in order to communicate on the VPN? My problem is that the client will be restricting by external IP address to their firewall, and this is changed each time the machine is shut down/powered up.

Comment: Hmm... Sounds like your gateway tenant was deleted and then re-created. When you say "the machine is shut down/powered up", did you shutdown ALL the machines in the Azure Virtual Network?

Comment: Yeah - we only have the one VM in Azure at the minute. Looks like the address that I was looking for would be the one assigned to the Azure Virtual Network Gateway. Thanks for the assistance.